# Ordering multiple posts using scopes ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to order the posts on my page using `ordered_by_title` and `ordered_by_reverse_created_at`.

I don't know if I'm doing this right but on my post_controller I have:

```
def ordered_by_title(order)

  @post = Post.order(:title)

end
```

and on my post.rb I have:

```
default_scope { ordered_by_title('title DESC') }
```

It seems to work good at ordering by the title of the posts but I'm not sure how I would also be able to order by reverse created at the same time. Any suggestions on how I might go about doing this?

Comment: You mean you want to have two simultaneous sort conditions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [scope inside another scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope), but not a method like you did inside a scope. write it inside the `Post` model, like :

```
scope :ordered_by_title, -> { order(:title) }
default_scope { ordered_by_title.order('title DESC') }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all in one scope.

```
# add the following line of code to post.rb
scope :order_by_title, -> {order(title: :desc, created_at: :desc)}
```

Update this line of code

```
@post = Post.order(:title)
```

to

```
@posts = Post.order_by_title
```

This will return all posts title descending. If two records have the same title, then the most recent record will show first. I added a `s` to `@post` because it will return multiple posts, so `@posts` made more sense than `@post`.

Comment: remove `.` from here `.order(ti...`